# Fastest way to transfer a file between two local web Ubuntu servers?

Tags: file, ubuntu, sharing

What is the fastest way to transfer a file between two Ubuntu web servers? The servers are local to each other. Would it be better to have a shared drive or to use a transfer protocol? Preferably with PHP facilitating the transfer between the two files.

Comment: What do you mean by "local to each other"? Do you mean that they are on the same internal network?

Comment: `scp` check it out. - also what has this got to do with PHP?! please tag appropriately.

Comment: @Lix Yes, local as in on the same network.

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 PHP is the technology being used on both servers and would be the preferred method of facilitating the transfer of the two files; my apologies I should of made this more clear in the post.

Comment: Are these physical machines or VMs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems the SCP command would be the best way to go about this. PHP provides a set of SSH2 functions in particular ssh2_scp_send http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php which appears to be the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is probably a question for unix/linux or server fault,I would say use the scp command, which is basically SSH CoPy. Get the IP address of the two machines, and use

```
scp USER@HOST1:/PATH/TO/FILE USER@HOST2:/PATH/TO/FILE
```

you will need to log in, and if you are copying a local file to a remote, you don't need anything for host 1, e.g.

```
scp /PATH/TO/LOCAL/FILE USER@HOST2:/PATH/TO/FILE
```

It works just like regular cp, except across systems. Make sure that both are running sshd (which they should).

If my commands are wrong, I've written this mostly from memory, so please leave a comment.

**EDIT**: At the time of writing there was no mention of PHP in the question other than it being tagged as such so I assumed he simply meant copying a file between two ubuntu servers.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to transfer a file between two computers that are either in the same location or physically near to each other would NOT be by USB storage device, but instead gigabit Ethernet as pointed out by others here.

I was actually thinking more of a simple, old school process.

But yeah, maybe a computer-computer network connection would be better?

**UPDATE:**
Actually, I see the OP is actually referring to two Virtual Machines, in which case none of my options would provide a solution at all. Sorry about that.

Comment: This.... This was my first thought... but I didn't have courage to post it :P The only limitation is if we are talking about VM servers in which case your solution would (obviously) not be possible. Lo-tech FTW!

Comment: You consider USB disks faster than GB Ethernet? Well, I see there are some strange people out there...